# How to change / remove cPanel default website page for mail.domain.com?

Tags: email, apache-http-server, cpanel, cname, whm

I have this default page showing up every time I visit mail.mydomain.com.

Here is a screenshot.

[image: cPanel default website page]

I don't want this page to show up like that or even show up at all. How can I prevent it from showing up, so any visitor won't be able to see the default website page message.

My website running on VPS WHM/cPanel, CentOS 6.5 64-bit.

I contacted my hosting provider and they said:

*"This is normal as, mail.domain.com is a 'cname' for your domain and is needed for your email to work correctly. Unfortunately changing this page would be custom configuration (branding) that is outside of our scope of managed support"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect via FTP to your website, go to the document root, and create, or edit, the file called `.htaccess`. Your document root should contain either `index.php` or `index.html` file. That's how you know it's the document root. If the file exists, edit it. Otherwise, create it.

Now, edit that file, and make sure you have the following content. Some lines may already be there. Add this content at the end. If it already contains `RewriteEngine On` - dont touch it and just add the next 2 out of 3 lines below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail\..*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F]
```

The first line enables the RewriteEngine. The second line specifies that the RewriteRule will work only if the domain starts with `mail.`. The final line, takes any request, and sends the `403 - Forbidden` HTTP status message.

This should work fine if the server used is `Apache HTTPD`, however if others, like `nginX` are used, you'd have to look how to do the same with them. For `nginX`, it would be something like this:

```
if ($host ~* ^mail\..*$ ) {
    return 444;
}
```

Sending a non-standard, 444 status, causes the connection to close, without sending any response. Alternatively you could send 403 if you want a "Forbidden" status.

Unfortunately I can't vouch for `nginX` since I've never used it. Maybe you'd need to write that to a different file or something. I don't know. But you probably have Apache HTTPD there.

Also, this question belongs on either stackoverflow.com, or serverfault.com.

Comment: It didn't work :( , I posted an edit to my question. Please see it and tell me If I placed the code in a wrong way. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MinaIsaac, why did you change the RewriteRule? (Your version would only work for the URLs like  `http://mail.mydomain.com/mydomain.com`.) And what does "it does not work" mean? No changes, or some error?

Comment: @MinaIsaac, if you want a more specific RewriteCond, then use this: `^mail\.mydomain\.com$` instead of what you used (though I wouldn't be so speciffic. At least don't put the dollar `$` sign at the end). And you changing the RewriteRule caused it not to work. Leave it to `^.*`. If the RewriteCond passes, then you already have a request to mail.mydomain.com. Any such request should be forbidden. Don't try to insert any more rules there. Especially that RewriteRule only checks the trailing path (ex. `/images/house.jpg`). It does not contain the domain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes it worked now but not for mail.mydomain.com, I tested it on another sub-domain and I got this domain blocked. The funny part here is that I can't get this sub-domain works again! lol :D Even after removing your provided code from the .htaccess, So I have mail.mydomain.com still loading the default website page and the subdomain that holds my clients' area is blocked! .. can you help me get the subdomain back to work again? Thank you very much in anyway :)

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out and the sub-domain worked again, but still have mail.mydomain.com redirecting to default page, if you have any suggestion please tell me. Many thanks :)

Comment: @MinaIsaac, why did you accept this as the solution if it didn't work?  Now future visitors will think it did work for you, so should also work for them. And what *exactly* did you use for your last test, and what was wrong that made the other domain be blocked? Again, things like "it does not work" and "I figured it out" are not helpful. And it seems to me that the text in your question is outdated.

Comment: @MinaIsaac, indeed, don't just accept an answer to close the issue and forget. If no answer fits your solution, then don't accept any. Listen to Arjan, tell us what's up. You've asked a question, now follow through so that the community could also gain from it.

Answer (score 0):

I am under the impression that the behavior of the default http response for "mail." + your domain is specific to the hosting company -- it's up to each company to configure it on their own, and different companies handle it differently.  So if your hosting company tells you that that's not user configurable on their system, they may well be right.  (Admittedly, there are other things hosting companies have told me weren't user configurable, which I figure out how to configure, but....)

I just checked some of my domains and others that I know the hosting companies of.  Some are configured to redirect to "www.", others to the hosting company's own main page!

If this is sufficiently important to you, you may be stuck trying to talk the hosting company into making a company-wide change (which... not impossible, their present solution is unprofessional looking and redirecting to "www." would be nicer all around) or moving your business elsewhere.

Comment: The page in the screenshot is just the default cPanel page, which apparently has not been changed by the hosting company. I quickly checked two cPanel accounts *on the very same server*: one shows the site's default index.html for *any* subdomain, while the other shows that default cPanel page instead. I couldn't quickly find any differences in related cPanel configurations, and I doubt DNS settings could be the culprit. Too bad that `/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi` is a compiled file, making it hard to see what it does exactly.